# How widespread is the use of the term 'sidemeat'?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

In *Grapes of Wrath* (1937) John Steinbeck uses the term *sidemeat*, sometimes hyphenated *side-meat*.

The OED confirms this is North American (I have never heard it used in Britain), and refers to salt pork or bacon, cut from the side of the pig. (Americans I discovered years ago don't eat back bacon.)

However one dictionary I looked in, specifically quoted *Grapes of Wrath*, suggesting that the term was unique to Steinbeck. The OED does give five references dating from 1868 to 1975. But clearly this is not a widely used term. Presumably Steinbeck mentions it to emphasise that his paupers were reduced to seeking out the cheapest cuts of meat. However the character 'Ma' (her name is never mentioned) talks about *sidemeat*. And if that sort of person would not normally have used the word in the 1930s, then presumably it would have sounded out of place in the text.

But I would be interested to know whether the word *sidemeat* is still used today, and whether there is, or has historically been, a particular stigma associated with purchase of sidemeat being indicative of poverty.

I would also be interested to know if Americans use the word *offal*, and how the eating of it links to an image of the poor.

Comment: My Irish farmer relatives in DeKalb County, IL used the term _side-meat_ to mean bacon; a typical farm breakfast often involved side meat and (cornmeal) mush, both fried. They were two generations older than me and I was born in 1942. It can be safely referred to as a rural N. American term from the Northern or Midlands regions (DeKalb Co. lies spang on the isogloss bundle between the two regions).

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sidemeat%2C+side-meat&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csidemeat%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cside%20-%20meat%3B%2Cc0

Comment: I've never heard this word before. I've heard of _offal_, but mostly as an archaic food.

Comment: In many developing countries, folks still wash and eat the offal: stomachs, small and large intestines, kidneys, etc of animals. In US that practice is long gone, along with the word. For awhile the intestines were used to form link sausage, but now that stuff is just ground up and put in hot dogs--still a low-end food.

Comment: I heard "side meat" when I was growing up in NW Ohio.  (I was born the same year as Lawler.)  I never heard "offal" -- that's a learned term, for me.

Comment: @JohnLawler That perfectly answers my question, and explains why Steinbeck used it. I'm only two years behind you (1944) of rural upbringing, and though we never used the word *sidemeat* certainly ate what another contributor has referred to as *link sausages* made from whole pork, as well as liver (which I loved) etc. ( All this is still widely enjoyed, except by those of an age where they need to count the cholesterol content!)

Comment: @JohnLawler Did they make soda bread too? I spent a summer, in my youth, working on a farm in Ireland (they were distant relatives). I especially remember the breakfasts and the home-made soda bread!

Comment: No, the bread was homemade, but it was white bread. There was a lot of corn bread, too.

Comment: The right type of answer will address where this expression is used exactly.

Comment: Note that what is called "[back bacon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back_bacon)" in the UK is called "Canadian bacon" in the U.S. and is commonly eaten here. Another cut of (mostly) fat from the back of a pig is called "[fatback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatback)" in the U.S. and is used as a flavoring in certain dishes such as pork and beans.

Comment: @SvenYargs The only countries in which I have had good quality bacon, apart from the UK is in Ireland and Australia. But I've never been to Canada. I've never seen proper bacon in the US - nor on American-owned cruitse ships.

Answer (score 2):

In a comment John Lawler wrote:

> My Irish farmer relatives in DeKalb County, IL used the term *side-meat* to mean bacon; a typical farm breakfast often involved side meat and (cornmeal) mush, both fried. They were two generations older than me and I was born in 1942. It can be safely referred to as a rural N. American term from the Northern or Midlands regions (DeKalb Co. lies spang on the isogloss bundle between the two regions).

Indeed, the term can be found in newspapers in the early to mid twentieth century, as a search of [Chronicling America](https://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/search/pages/results/?state=&date1=1770&date2=1963&proxtext=sidemeat&x=0&y=0&dateFilterType=yearRange&rows=20&searchType=basic) illustrates.

Here is a reference to sidemeat as bacon ([The oasis. [volume]](https://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn85032933/1910-08-20/ed-1/seq-9/) (Arizola, Ariz.), 20 Aug. 1910. Chronicling America: Historic American Newspapers. Lib. of Congress.).

> Bacon! Thy name was once as low
> As was thy price;
> We would not in
> the long ago,
> Think of thee twice.
> Thou wert not meet to grace the
> board
> Where pomp and pride meet --
> In the dark smokehouse wert thou
> stored
> As common sidemeat.

To show geographic range, the term also appears in a newspaper in Kentucky ([The Mt. Sterling advocate](https://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn86069675/1913-11-05/ed-1/seq-1/). (Mt. Sterling, Ky.), 05 Nov. 1913. Chronicling America: Historic American Newspapers. Lib. of Congress.):

> Late garden truck is about all gone, and hog killing time is drawing near, but few hogs are to be found for sale and there will be a big scarcity of meat in that line this winter and prices will be very high on sausage, hams and sidemeat

As well as Idaho ([The silver messenger](https://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn88056158/1899-07-18/ed-1/seq-1/). (Challis, Idaho), 18 July 1899. Chronicling America: Historic American Newspapers. Lib. of Congress.):

> Singing ballads, playing cards, Eating sidemeat, and running guards

And [Washington DC](https://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn83045462/1959-08-16/ed-1/seq-5/) in the 1950s (Evening star. [volume] (Washington, D.C.), 16 Aug. 1959. Chronicling America: Historic American Newspapers. Lib. of Congress.):

> For all practical purposes, Mr. Butler has told the South to go fry its sidemeat. He wants the Democrats, as a party, to stand up and be counted in favor of racial integration in the schools and other public places.

And in the 1950s in Maryland, an advertiser could post about "pork side meat" ([The Republican](https://chroniclingamerica.loc.gov/lccn/sn88065202/1956-10-11/ed-1/seq-8/). [volume] (Oakland, Md.), 11 Oct. 1956. Chronicling America: Historic American Newspapers. Lib. of Congress.):

[image]

So, at the very least, this was a term for a certain kind of meat that was once used across the US, maybe more frequently in rural areas but appearing from the west to the east coast.